# Docker container stopped running

Tags: docker

I have built an image in docker and I am running  container having the image  docker but it got exited after one day. I want it running forever. What command to use?

I have tried the command "docker run -d -p  <container_name>".

Answer (score 2):

You can put `restart: always` in YML file or you can run in command line `docker run --restart=always`